# Decoding a google protobuff message after receiving it from a Web Socket in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, websocket, protocol-buffers

I am listening to a WebSocket and this WebSocket returns the data encoded in a Base64 binary bytes which is encoded by Google protobuff. I can't seem to find a way to decode it using Node.JS. Example of a data that was received:

> CLP5gBASK3RibmIxbnVwZXB2dHloMGo3eHQ1czVsOTcwYTZ4YXJzcTZtNnB3bGE5eGgaFAoHQUxULTNCNhD58I/HAiCA35glGhAKA0JOQhCKsa2iASDQwPot

Edit 1:

This is the schema I am looking for:

```
message Account{
    int64 Height = 1;
    string owner = 2;
    repeated AssetBalance Balances = 3;
}

message AssetBalance{
    string Asset = 1;
    int64 Free = 2;
    int64 Frozen = 3;
    int64 Locked = 4;
}
```

I need to use the Account message I assume as the AssetBalance is here as it is a type inside Account.

Edit 2:

Fixed. the below solution works well. No need to use .result though. The eventual JSON Descriptor I used eventually was:

```
{
"nested": {
    "Account": {
        "fields": {
            "Height": {
                "type": "int64",
                "id": 1
            },
            "owner": {
                "type": "string",
                "id": 2
            },
            "Balances": {
                "repeated": true,
                "type": "AssetBalance",
                "id": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "AssetBalance": {
        "fields": {
            "Asset": {
                "type": "string",
                "id": 1
            },
            "Free": {
                "type": "int64",
                "id": 2
            },
            "Frozen": {
                "type": "int64",
                "id": 3
            },
            "Locked": {
                "type": "int64",
                "id": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this approach:

```
var protobuf = require("protobufjs");
protobuf.parse.defaults.keepCase = true;
let root = protobuf.Root.fromJSON(JSON.parse("your json")
var message = root.lookupType("your type");
var buf = Buffer.from("CLP5gBASK3RibmIxbnVwZXB2dHloMGo3eHQ1czVsOTcwYTZ4YXJzcTZtNnB3bGE5eGgaFAoHQUxULTNCNhD58I/HAiCA35glGhAKA0JOQhCKsa2iASDQwPot","hex");
message.decode(buf).result;
```

more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs

Sample: https://github.com/maiconpintoabreu/Proto-Sample

Comment: So I understand that I need a schema for protobuffs. Where does the schema goes? into the json or the type? And what is the other var that this lib needs? Thanks!

Comment: you can use .json or .proto

Json:
`{
    "nested": {
        "List": {
            "fields": {
                "result": {
                    "rule": "repeated",
                    "type": "Item",
                    "id": 1
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "Item": {
                    "fields": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "id": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: `var message = root.lookupType("List"); //if you expect a array`
`var message = root.lookupType("Item"); //if you expect an object`

Proto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs#using-proto-files

Comment: if you do not know the fields use this link: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode

Comment: Your help is really appriciated. As I am new to this would you mind helping me with the last thing I do not completly undestand? I have added the scheme I am looking for in the original message. What I need to do is turn it into a json that is compatible with the proto file? and then the lookuptype will be an Item I assume

Comment: Hi @Contentop check this: https://github.com/maiconpintoabreu/Proto-Sample

Comment: Awesome, I feel like I am doing the same thing as you do and I get an error. Adding to original message now

Comment: NVM, my JSON was wrong. This solution is great but the .result at the end should be removed. What I needed was in message.decode(buf). Thanks!